# This support library should not use a different version, error in build.gradle

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-support-library

There is one problem in my `build.gradle`. The error in the gradle is that ( `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0-beta1'`)  on this line the error display that (This support library should not use a different version(24 ) then the compile sdk version 23)
Any idea? And I used Android Studio 2.1.2 and the main problem is that in Android studio there is no android support library. pic is below

[image]

Answer (score 26):

Your `compileSdkVersion` is `23` in the `build.gradle` file but you're trying to use `appcompat-v7:24.0.0` which is for API 24, so you should use `appcompat-v7:23.x.y` for API 23. If you still want to use `appcompat-v7:24.0.0` then you should change the `compileSdkVersion` to 24

You should use this for `compileSdkVersion` 23:

> compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'

and this for `compileSdkVersion` 24 :

> compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0'

**Edit**

If you work on Android Studio, then you probably don't need to worry about the latest version available, it'll let you know about the latest available version.

You can also check the latest versions available for every sdk version [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions.html)

Comment: How can we know which versions are available for specific SDKs? Or we should just change compileSdkVersion once a newer version is available?

Comment: @Petar-Krešimir you can check https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions.html for the latest version of support library, also Android Studio will remind you when there is a new version of support libraries available

Comment: @Petar-Krešimir You could browse https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/

Comment: now it shows , google play does not support SDK 23 !? in intellij and compile is not supported(obsuleter) should be changed to implementation in most cases

Answer (score 4):

Yep, they must not be different. Change it to `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'`

Comment: Thank you sir. i really appreciate and it work correctly

Comment: No problem. :) I would appreciate if you mark this answer as correct.

Comment: @BorislavKamenov I'm asking a little late. But why? What if i set them different.

Comment: Because Google guarantee that the libraries with same version are working properly and issues/bugs may happened in case of incompatibilities between different versions. So its better and good practice to keep all of them with same version. Its even better to keep all of them to older version, instead of specifying different versions.