# Gradle asks for nonexistent support library version

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-gradle-2.2

Recently I've been getting this problem.

[image]
As far as I know, there is no 26.X.X versions of these support libraries, what does Gradle wants from me?

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in your Compile version in build.gradle file.
It seems, your compile version is 26.
Please change your compile version to 25 and sync gradle.

```
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"
```

Comment: [Gradle is still not happy](https://image.prntscr.com/image/x46oaZNhSjWgW60yKcIF3Q.png)

Answer (score 0):

After reviewing a previous question, you may want to be sure that your compileSdkVersion matches across the board, if you want to build in 25 but you are in 23.

[This support library should not use a different version Error in build.gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38072185/this-support-library-should-not-use-a-different-version-error-in-build-gradle)

You can confirm versions by >> Create new project in Android studio >> Press Ctrl+Shift+Alt+S >> Proceed to 'Project' section >> You can see actual gradle version and android pluging version. Copy that to your project.

Answer (score 0):

**Please set your Compile Version to 25**

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.user.xxxxx"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
```

Comment: [Gradle is still not happy](https://image.prntscr.com/image/x46oaZNhSjWgW60yKcIF3Q.png)