# i want add compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0' in dependencies but this compile is error

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I would like to create tab-layout and add dependencies compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0' but he error simultaneously with 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1',
please help

[this is code in mydependencies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5GSAq.png)

Comment: you should put the code inside dependencies code block,not outside.

Comment: @JohnJoe 
He is already in dependencies, sorry the picture is not shown ful

Comment: what are the error you getting ?

Comment: @JohnJoe "This support library should not use a different version(23) than the 'compileSdkVersion' (25)

Comment: @JohnJoe please help me..

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38072185/this-support-library-should-not-use-a-different-version-error-in-build-gradle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason of that error is that you are using different versions of the compatibility library.

Instead of this: compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'

use this: Use this instead: compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'

Also I recommend you to use a variable to keep consistency like below:

```
ext {
    supportLibVersion = '25.3.1'  // variable that can be referenced to keep support libs consistent
}

dependencies {
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${supportLibVersion}"
    compile "com.android.support:design:${supportLibVersion}"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this library for Version-25 in gradle.

```
-> compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
```